# iOS programming: Class and Instance

Tags: ios

I think I might ask a fool question but it does confuse me for a while.

I am a beginner for iOS developing and the example I have seen online that people always write code inside the viewController's class.

However, according to my experience in C++, I think a class is just a template for reuse. You can only use it when it has been initialized.
So the thing that performs the work is the instance.

My question would be when/who create the viewController instance in an app?

Comment: Are you doing everything in code or do you use storyboards?

Comment: @rmaddy Probably storyboards. If OP was doing everything in code, then they would see how VCs are instantiated because they would be doing it themselves

Comment: This is a very good question. I had confusion this myself, when I first started out

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, that occurred to me seconds after posting my comment.

Comment: The [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) will probably help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you are referring to the template `ViewController`, the one that always comes with a new single page application project, for instance.

It's being created "under the hood" once your app finishes launching, but what it is basically doing is the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    window?.rootViewController = ViewController();
    return true
}
```

In fact, that's what you need to do if you want to delete your storyboard and work fully programmatically, in addition to clearing the **Main Interface** info in you project's general info as follows:

[image: Leave the Main Interface info blank]

And if you want to show another custom `ViewController` class, you can present it from another `ViewController` as in

```
let secondViewController = MyCustomViewController()
// this line will place the MyCustomViewController instance on top of the current ViewController
present(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I hope I could help!

Comment: Doesn't the `Main Interface` only specify a xib/nib/storyboard? The instantiation of the VC is then done from there. I can't check myself right now

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly it. I pointed it out just in case he wants to try running a ViewController without storyboard. If it's not blank, it won't work (at least until Xcode 8.3)